# How to derive a new column based on other columns comparisions in Hive?

Tags: sql, hive

I have huge table and 2 columns A and B in hive.
Rows are identical where either A or B or both have same values.
I would like to build a new column and assign a value based on this comparision :

```
A    B
--   --
a    b
a    c
d    b
p    q
```

Result :

```
A    B    New_Col
--   --   -----
a    b     id1
a    c     id1
d    b     id1
p    q     id2
```

Any efficient solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [conditional functions in Hive](http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/conditional-functions-in-hive.html) in your SELECT statement:

```
SELECT A, B, IF(A == 'a' OR B == 'b', 'id1', 'id2') AS New_Col FROM huge_table;
```

Here's how to create a `new_huge_table` from your `huge_table` with the new, derived column `New_Col`:

```
CREATE TABLE my_database.new_huge_table (A STRING, B STRING, New_Col STRING);
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE my_database.new_huge_table
SELECT A, B, IF(A == 'a' OR B == 'b', 'id1', 'id2') AS New_Col FROM huge_table;
```